# How to pick a random value from a collection in Scala

Tags: scala

I need a method to pick uniformly a random value from a collection.

Here is my current impl.

```
implicit class TraversableOnceOps[A, Repr](val elements: TraversableOnce[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def pickRandomly : A = elements.toSeq(Random.nextInt(elements.size))
}
```

But this code instantiate a new collection, so not ideal in term of memory.

Any way to improve ?

**[update]** make it work with `Iterator`

```
  implicit class TraversableOnceOps[A, Repr](val elements: TraversableOnce[A]) extends AnyVal {
    def pickRandomly : A = {
      val seq = elements.toSeq
      seq(Random.nextInt(seq.size))
    }
  }
```

Comment: Also your method won't work because if you call `elements.size` you will consume the iterator, making it impossible to then call `toSeq`.

Comment: Can you redesign your code so that you can pass through the size or use a specific collection that keeps track of its size without relying on an iterator?

Comment: @dhg, it can be done. Granted, you will have to iterator over all of them, but  it can be done with O(1) memory.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It may seem at first glance that you can't do this without counting the elements first, but you can!

Iterate through the sequence *f* and take each element *f<sub>i</sub>* with probability *1/i*:

```
def choose[A](it: Iterator[A], r: util.Random): A =
  it.zip(Iterator.iterate(1)(_ + 1)).reduceLeft((x, y) =>
    if (r.nextInt(y._2) == 0) y else x
  )._1
```

A quick demonstration of uniformity:

```
scala> ((1 to 1000000)
     | .map(_ => choose("abcdef".iterator, r))
     | .groupBy(identity).values.map(_.length))
res45: Iterable[Int] = List(166971, 166126, 166987, 166257, 166698, 166961)
```

[Here's](http://chris-martin.org/2009/randomization-pipeline/) a discussion of the math I wrote a while back, though I'm afraid it's a bit unnecessarily long-winded. It also generalizes to choosing any fixed number of elements instead of just one.

Comment: This is a solution to this problem that I've seen quite frequently, and it's not clear to me why it is superior to the approach I outline below.  For a sufficiently large range of random numbers, the `maxBy` approach seems much simpler, arbitrarily paralellizable, independent of the distribution of the random numbers, and easily generalizeable to top n scenarios.   The slight bias caused by ties is negligible.

Comment: The linked page points out this works in constant space, unlike your solution. Feel free to actually argue the advantages of your approach. For starters, it's not obvious how to parallelize random-number generation properly (see http://www.sprng.org/; the thing isn't that hard, but it's not trivial either).

Comment: @Blaisorblade user295691's answer uses constant space as well.

Comment: @user295691, your approaches requires more random generation than this one. This one increases the random range each time as necessary. Yours uses a fixed high randomness each time, high enough to be sufficient for any possible number of elements.

Comment: Might I suggest `zipWithIndex`? `it.zipWithIndex.reduceLeft((x, y) => if (r.nextInt(y._2 + 1) == 0) y else x)._1`

Comment: @PaulDraper I thought constructing a sequence from 1 was more clear than adjusting it with +1 later.

Comment: need a `toIterator` to make it work for every `TraversableOnce` ?

Comment: @PaulDraper "more random generation" is a little vague; we each call Random.nextInt the same number of times; and the bounding of the randomness is actually more costly than unrestricted.

Comment: @user295691, it could be; IDK what the OpenJDK implementation is. It's possible to run the PRNG less (on average) for smaller numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way is just to think of the problem as zipping the collection with an equal-sized list of random numbers, and then just extract the maximum element.  You can do this without actually realizing the zipped sequence.  This does require traversing the entire iterator, though

```
val maxElement = s.maxBy(_=>Random.nextInt)
```

Or, for the implicit version

```
implicit class TraversableOnceOps[A, Repr](val elements: TraversableOnce[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def pickRandomly : A = elements.maxBy(_=>Random.nextInt)
}
```

Comment: I like this. It would be interesting to write a variant where instead of generating integers of a fixed size, you associate an bit array with each element, and only lengthen them when there's a tie. That would remove the little bit of bias, and let you really skimp on entropy, since most elements can be eliminated after only a couple coin tosses rather than 32 or 64.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to select an element *uniformly at random* from a collection, *traversing it once* without copying the collection.

The following algorithm will do the trick:

```
def choose[A](elements: TraversableOnce[A]): A = {
    var x: A = null.asInstanceOf[A]
    var i = 1

    for (e <- elements) {
        if (Random.nextDouble <= 1.0 / i) {
            x = e
        }

        i += 1
    }

    x
}
```

The algorithm works by at each iteration makes a choice: take the new element with probability `1 / i`, or keep the previous one.

To understand why the algorithm choose the element uniformly at random, consider this: Start by considering an element in the collection, for example the first one (in this example the collection only has three elements).

At iteration:

1. Chosen with probability: 1.
2. Chosen with probability:
   (probability of keeping the element at previous iteration) * (keeping at current iteration)
   probability => 1 * 1/2 = 1/2
3. Chosen with probability: 1/2 * 2/3=1/3 (in other words, uniformly)

If we take another element, for example the second one:

1. 0 (not possible to choose the element at this iteration).
2. 1/2.
3. 1/2*2/3=1/3.

Finally for the third one:

1. 0.
2. 0.
3. 1/3.

This shows that the algorithm selects an element uniformly at random. This can be proved formally using induction.

Answer (score 0):

If the collection is large enough that you care about about instantiations, here is the constant memory solution (I assume, it contains ints' but that only matters for passing initial param to `fold`):

```
collection.fold((0, 0)) { 
  case ((0, _), x) => (1, x)
  case ((n, x), _) if (random.nextDouble() > 1.0/n) => (n+1, x)
  case ((n, _), x) => (n+1, x)
}._2
```

I am not sure if this requires a further explanation ... Basically, it does the same thing that @svenslaggare suggested above, but in a functional way, since this is tagged as a scala question.